# google spreadsheet update same row from multiple files

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I'm currently involved in a local political campaign.

**Master File**

I have one master file with about 30,000 voters in a large geographical area. I have some basic information about each voter (like ID, city or phone number) and some gained information about each of them (like when did we last talk to them, which volunteer knows them or what is their political affiliation).

**Shared files**

Although I can't share this file with a lot of people I do need to share portions of that data with different people.

A few examples:

1. I want the volunteer team in each city to have the list of the registered voters in that city - so that they can call them.
2. I also want each volunteer to have a list of people whom he knows and or been in contact with. Obviously, this two lists have interlapping data and I need to be able to update them from both of those files.
3. Also, I want to be able to update those rows from my master file - so that I can easily enter some data I get in bulk.

I don't know of any way to implement this. Is this even possible in google sheets? Is there another online free web tool that I could use?

thanks

Comment: Please share some mock data to work with (how the data looks and expected result, perhaps a google sheet link)and what also share what you have tried so far?

Comment: This post is two years old, I'm not sure person posting will reply.

Comment: @JasonAllshorn Hi! I'm back in 2018. Are there hoverboards in the future, yet? ;)

Comment: "Is this possible?" - sure, everything is possible, but that's a broad ["Where do I Start?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/179952) question. "Is there another tool?" - S/W recommendations are not [on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Putting effort into improving your question will do more to get you a _good answer_ than a bounty will. If you really want someone to provide code or a solution from your specification - hire them. For a SW Rec, try [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) - although your question may be off-topic there, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's possible, but you have to make a lot of script work.

Here are some thoughts.

**1. Why script**

You can't achieve this with help of `importrange` function for 3 reasons:

1. **Security**.  Each volonteer will have a potential access to all your data.
2. **Speed**. `Importrange` will dramatically slow down your calculations.
3. **View only**. The formula result is view-only, no edits can be done.

---

**2. Data design**

To help yourself with a script work, you may consider creating:

1. `IDs` for each row in each file.
2. `IDs` for fields (columns) in each file.

The first row in each sheet may contain column ID:

```
 1       2               3           4
ID    city    phone number         ...
```

---

**3. Writing a script**

When you deal with a script, you have some limits:

1. A script can't run online, you'll have to use [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), and run each hour.
2. You can't run a trigger each minute because you'll deal with Google [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

As you have 3 conflicting types of files, you have to decide, which changes are main.

```
Main File > Team File > Member File.
```

One possible way to solve conflicts is to use a [timestamp](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=timestamp%20for%20google%20sheets&oq=timestamp%20for%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4613j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for changes in respective fields.

---

**Conclusion**

[google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) is probably, could be replaced with a good CRM in your case.

Please see the [Importer](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2018/04/10/importer/), my project for doing import with a script.

Comment: Bounties are tempting, aren't they? They don't make questions any better, though - this question is a specification looking for someone to provide a design or solution. Off-topic questions should be edited to be on-topic, or closed - answering just encourages more bad questions. [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: @Mogsdad, Thanks for the comment, but I'm among a few people, who disagree with that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361785/5372400

Comment: @fingerman, I've added the link to my sample script. Hope, this helps!