# Update content from query selected table

Tags: google-sheets

thanks to all,

Is there a simple way to change the content from a table that is referenced by a query from other sheets without breaking the query.
I have a couple of sheets that I'm pulling data from to a master sheet, but I want to edit the updates on the master without going to the individual sheets.
here is my query:

```
QUERY({orange!A2:I24;'apple'!A2:I26;'banana'!A2:I26},"select Col1,Col2 where Col7 ='sold'OR Col7= 'shipped',1)
```

hope I'm clear, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The formula result is read-only.
That's correct for a `query` or any other array-formula.

You could achieve this using a script:
https://www.google.com/script/start/

With help of a script you may achieve this:

1. Complete your goal, update the values from multiple sheets and backward. Please see how to deal with [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
2. Make your task on a regular base, use [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). It may run each minute, hour etc.

Please also see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376999/5372400) on the related topic.

Comment: Hey thanks, any idea what to be looking for in making the script ? by the way I have a different approach maybe you know if it is possible. I was thinking maybe I can make a separate column outside of the query, but the issue is keeping the content inline with all the other rows with the table updates. because currently when the query is updated the rows don't  match on the new column that been made hope I'm clear cheers :)

Comment: I've added some links. Actually, you are asking about a very hard task to be done, it's a complex and needs a lot of script work.

Comment: I'm sure haha, thanks a lot man for the great info appreciate that I will go over the stuff ,cheers.